# Set Image to the left of text in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Sorry for  a noob question, I think it should be done with Spannable or something, but I can't google it right.

I need a text in a TextView with a drawable to the left of each line . How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

By using XML

Use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"` to your `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

By using Code

Youe can see [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sampleImage"` in TextView Tag in XML file.

Answer (score 0):

see this property of `TextView`

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourIcon"

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/TextView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourIcon"
  android:ems="10"
  android:text="TextView" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="10dip" />
```

you can even use a linearlayout with orientation vertical with one ImageView and Textview in that align textView layout to center